# Create an xml node tree from a result set but combining repeated attributes using linq or expressions

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, linq

Hi I have a dataset in the following format:

```
NodeID | NodeName | NodeAttribute1 | NodeAttribute2
   1   |    n1    |       1        |      null
   2   |    n2    |       1        |      null
   3   |    n3    |       1        |        1
   4   |    n4    |       2        |        2
   5   |    n5    |       2        |        3
   6   |    n6    |       2        |        4
```

Basically, the attributes determine the position of the node in the virtual tree. I want the result to look like this:

```
<NodeTree>
    <ParentNodeType1 NodeAttribute1 = 1> 
        <node name="n1" nodeID=1>
        <node name="n2" nodeID=2>
        <ParentNodeType2 NodeAttribute2 = 1>
            <node name = "n3" nodeID = 3>
        </ParentNodeType2>
    </ParentNodeType1>
    <ParentNodeType1 NodeAttribute1 = 2> 
        <ParentNodeType2 NodeAttribute2 = 3>
            <node name = "n4" nodeID=4>
        </ParentNodeType2>
        <ParentNodeType2 NodeAttribute2 = 4>
            <node name = "n5" nodeID=5>
            <node name = "n6" nodeID=6>
        </ParentNodeType2>
    </ParentNodeType1>
</NodeTree>
```

So n1 and n2 are in parent1 but n3 is one level deeper because the second attribute is not null. Anyone have any thoughts on how this might be done using linq or something like that?

Comment: Thanks to Eduardo for cleaning up my table..New to this site..

Comment: Incidentally, I think Eduardo also messed up the data. The original table corresponded a lot better with the XML snippet... Irony

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I tried to make sense of this, but I failed.

*Your data seems not described very well (what are the attributes? Why don't you want the hierarchy mapped in XML? What are ParentNodeType1/2 supposed to be? NodeAttribute2 appears to be the parent-node-ID, yet in the XML nodes n5 and n6 are both under `<ParentNodeType2 NodeAttribute2 = 4>` I wasn't smart enough to detect the logic there :)*

In an attempt to help you nonetheless, here is what I *think* would be useful, and you can simply adapt it to your 'requirements' without me having to know about it (wink wink)

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace X 
{ 
    static class Y 
    {
        public static int Main(string[] args)
        {
            var data = new Record[] {
                new Record(1, "n1", 1, null),
                    new Record(2, "n2", 1, null),
                    new Record(3, "n3", 1, 1),
                    new Record(4, "n4", 2, 2),
                    new Record(5, "n5", 2, 3),
                    new Record(6, "n6", 2, 4),
            };

            Func<Record, XElement> subtree;
            subtree = node => new XElement("node", 
                    new XAttribute("name", node.NodeName),
                    new XAttribute("nodeID", node.NodeID),
                    new XAttribute("NodeAttribute1", node.NodeAttribute1),
                    data.ChildrenOf(node.NodeID).Select(subtree));

            XElement xml = new XElement("NodeTree",
                    data.Where(root => root.NodeAttribute2 == null)
                    .Select(subtree));

            Console.WriteLine(xml);
            return 0;
        }

        struct Record
        {
            public readonly int NodeID;
            public readonly string NodeName;
            public readonly int  NodeAttribute1; //level?
            public readonly int? NodeAttribute2; //parent

            internal Record(int id, string name, int at1, int? at2) 
            {
                NodeID = id;
                NodeName = name;
                NodeAttribute1 = at1;
                NodeAttribute2 = at2;
            }
        }

        private static IEnumerable<Record> ChildrenOf(this IEnumerable<Record> data, int? parentId)
        {
            return data.Where(child => child.NodeAttribute2 == parentId);
        }
    }
}
```

Oh just in case, here is the output

```
<NodeTree>
  <node name="n1" nodeID="1" NodeAttribute1="1">
    <node name="n3" nodeID="3" NodeAttribute1="1">
      <node name="n5" nodeID="5" NodeAttribute1="2" />
    </node>
  </node>
  <node name="n2" nodeID="2" NodeAttribute1="1">
    <node name="n4" nodeID="4" NodeAttribute1="2">
      <node name="n6" nodeID="6" NodeAttribute1="2" />
    </node>
  </node>
</NodeTree>
```

Comment: I apologize for not being clear enough. I just conjured up this example to help understand what kind of code would be needed to get this sort of thing done.I am basically exploring different ideas for storing hierarchical data. The main idea behind it is each row would have enough information to let you know where it belongs in the tree. Each attribute column represents a level in the tree. Thank you for your reply though..

Comment: Ok, for an exploratory query, I think my sample should give you solid ideas. (Also, I tuned down on the rant after getting your intentions and discovering that the post was mis-edited by someone else). Cheers

Comment: Your interpretation of having all of them as the same type of element makes sense. I guess my data or at least my explanation of it does not describe the node parents. The real data I am working with is a lot more complex than this so please bear with me as I try to present the core problem. Which is rebuilding the tree based on the level attribute fields. I added in the node parent  just as a thought.